# Does anyone know when google fcm stop supporting legacy HTTP API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have read the doc entirely and googled with question, but cannot find when google fcm stop supporting legacy HTTP API. Considering if is soon expires, I may not choose to use it in project, whereas use http v1, howvever, I have some issue calling http v1 api.

Comment: If you're starting a new project, why would you not use the new API?

Answer (score 6):

Deprecation in the FAQ here: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#fcm-23-deprecation

or refer to [Puf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76531311/4625829).

---

<s>There is currently still no announcement when the legacy API will be deprecated. AFAICT, it will still be usable for a long time, since most users still have the Legacy API implemented.</s>

Don't let the *Legacy* in the name let you think it is no longer good to use. v1 is just advisable to use since it uses the OAuth 2 security model (see this [Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/11/whats-new-with-fcm-customizing-messages.html)).

With that said, I second Puf's comment, if you are just about to start a new project, why not go for v1?

Comment: thanks, I agree legacy http api will be in use for a long time, cause I am in mobile gaming segment, so I am afraid one day in future google play may reject our package due to the reason that api is deprecated. I tried to use v1, everything is good but response keeps saying 411 content-length not named.

Comment: I am getting HTTP 403 error(SENDER_ID_MISMATCH). I don't know where i am missing something. Is there any checklist to this type of error?

Comment: @NagarajN Mismatch Sender ID generally means you're trying to send a message to a token that is not associated with your sender. Try generating a new token (make sure it's associated with yours) and sending a test message there. I don't know what you mean by a checklist, but the error response codes can be seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) (for FCM Legacy)

Comment: @AL.Thanks for the suggestion. It got fixed after changing the class GoogleCredential to GoogleCredentials to generate token.

Comment: An announcement about this actually just was sent to all users of legacy, non-versioned API. If you didn't receive that message (or even if you did), you can read the FAQ here: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#fcm-23-deprecation

Answer (score 5):

*firebaser here*

Firebase just sent an email to all owners of projects that still use the FCM legacy API. The gist of the message is that the legacy FCM API is now officially deprecated and you should move to the versioned API.

You can also find the information in the [FAQ on FCM features deprecated in June 2023](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#fcm-23-deprecation). From there:

> **Will I see a service downgrade before June 2024?**
>
> No. You have 12 months (06/20/2023 - 06/21/2024) to migrate from the old APIs to new APIs without any service downgrade. We strongly recommend you to plan the migration as early as possible so you won’t be impacted by the decommissioning of the APIs in June 2024.
>
> After June 2024, you may see increased errors or lack of functionality when using the APIs/SDKs listed above.

But please read the entire section in the link, as there's a wealth of information - including a list of the affected APIs, and their replacement.

The versioned API is fully covered in the Firebase documentation on [sending messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) for example on [building send requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message). If you have code that still uses the legacy API, there's also a page on [migrating from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1).